# Best way to store n size-2 numeric vectors?

Tags: r, vector

One of the projects I'm working on (in R) involves storing n different confidence intervals from n samples, and each confidence interval is represented as a numeric vector of size 2 (so, for instance, if an interval is `c(1, 2)`, the left end of the interval is 1, and right is 2).

I need a way to store n of these vectors. I've tried using a data frame, but I can't seem to get it to work. Which data structure should I use to store/keep track of all these vectors? I don't think there's such a thing as a "vector of vectors"? I'm fairly new to R, and not quite familiar with all the data structures. Thanks!

Comment: How about an nx2 matrix?

Comment: Alternatively to the excellent suggestion by @G5W, you could use a list. Even naming each vector to reference the source sample.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I could use a list. I will be creating the n confidence intervals in a while loop; if I just do ``intervals <- list()``, will I be able to store the confidence intervals as I create them?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways.

You could store them as

- A data frame with one column as the first value and another column as the second value.
- Elements of a list.
- A nx2 matrix.

What it comes down to is how will the data be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think a list of vectors would be best here, try this sample code:

```
x <- c(0,1)
y  <- c(0.25,0.75)
z <- c(0.1,0.9)

li <- list(x,y,z)
```

from here, you can access individual confidence intervals by square bracket indexing to select the index of the desired confidence interval. ie:`li[[confidence interval]]`